# IPhone: Select all text in a textview

Tags: iphone

I'd like to implement a button that basically selects all the text I have in a textview for easier editing. How do I do so?

Answer (score 1):

use selectedRange property, but, as mentioned in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006898-CH3-SW10), onlyiPhone OS 3.0 and later.